# Imagem do produto no <option> do <select> é possível?

Tags: jquery, html5

Tenho um sistema de orçamentos mas como são muitos ítens com descrição semelhantes surgiu a necessidade de visualizar a imagem junto a descrição, o link da imagem e a descrição será dinâmica e virá de um banco de dados, fiz um código para exemplificar a necessidade, mas este funciona apenas no firefox, lembrando fiz somente para exemplificar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#img_1').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#image_1').show();
    });
    $('#img_1').mouseout(function(){
       $('#image_1').hide();
    });
    $('#img_2').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#image_2').show();
    });
    $('#img_2').mouseout(function(){
       $('#image_2').hide();
    });
    $('#img_3').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#image_3').show();
    });
    $('#img_3').mouseout(function(){
       $('#image_3').hide();
    });
})
```

```css
img{
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(230, 76, 16, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(230, 76, 16, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px orange;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="img">Selecione um ítem: </label>
  <select name="imgs" id="imgs">
                <option value="img_1" id="img_1">Img 1</option>
                <option value="img_2" id="img_2">Img 2</option>
                <option value="img_3" id="img_3">Img 3</option>
            </select>
  <figure>
    <img style="display: none;" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics/" alt="Imagem 1" id="image_1">
    <img style="display: none;" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics/" alt="Imagem 2" id="image_2">
    <img style="display: none;" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics/" alt="Imagem 3" id="image_3">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) é somente permitido texto. Documentação da MDN:

> Conteúdo permitido: Texto, possivelmente com caracateres escapados (como `&eacute;`).

Com jQuery uma opção é o [selectMenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render).

Comment: Valeu me ajudou com esta dica, não tinha lido a documentação.